# Updating the status picklist

Tags: field-update, trigger

I'm using custom objects and one of the requirement I have is:

When an "Assigned user" (lookup) and "start date" (date field) is set  then update the "status" (picklist) to `Scheduled`

my question is:

What is the best way to approach should I write trigger to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the relation ship between the status picklist and the other fields. Does they exist on the same object. If so workflow is enough to update the status picklist. Even the status picklist is on parent object workflow is enough. But where as the User and start date fields are on parent object and status is on child you need to opt for the trigger.

Comment: there is no relationship between two fields and both field are on the same custom object

Comment: From your comment what I understood is your 3 fields  Lookup ,start date and status fields are on the same object if so then Create a workflow such that Assigned User != null and start date != null  using field update feature update the status field

Comment: yep that's correct but now i started using workflow rule and I'm confused now should it be based on `criteria` or `formula` ?

Comment: you mean you want to make you picklist field as formula field, if the field gets auto update based on formula that is fine, but what if some one need to change it  manually. What are the other values in the picklist and how they are handling with the record types. please consider all this before turning it to formula.

Comment: I did not say I want to make it picklist as formula field but what I'm trying to say is... should go with criteria or formula?

Comment: okay here is my first attempt: field is my `start_date`, operator = `not equal to` and what should be the `value` ?

Comment: any thing is fine as long as your conditions are simple. if the complexity grows opt for the formula. if you go with criteria. start_date, operator = not equal to null